# Get value from call to any

Tags: python

I have a list of objects and they all have a data member `visited`.

`visited` is a boolean, default is `False`.

I would like to be able to iterate over the list of objects to find an object that has not been visited.

If all the objects have been visited I want to detect that and set another boolean called `done_searching` to `False`.

Here is some pseudo code of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
done_searching = False
while not done_searching:
    objects = [object1, object2, object3]

    foreach object in objects:
        if object.visited == False:
            non_visited_object = object
            break
        else if object.visited == True and last object in list
            done_searching = True
            break out of foreach

    non_visited_object.do_something()

    if (done_searching == True)
        break out of main
```

I also had an idea that I could somehow use `any()`... But it doesn't appear to work that way. Understandable loss of scope is the issue..

For example:

```
if any(object.visited == False for object in objects):
    object.do_something()
else
    searching_done = True
```

Comment: To get the first element of an array matching a criterion, use this: `next(obj for obj in objects if not obj.visited)`.

Comment: `any` doesn't leak the loop variable, and doesn't return the first truth-y result. If you want that behaviour, use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: @DSM: Done. I wasn't sure what the OP was asking, so I didn't realize that was the complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first element of an array matching a criterion, use this:

```
next(obj for obj in objects if not obj.visited)
```

To have it return `None` if nothing is found, as @DSM said, use the default parameter:

```
next((obj for obj in objects if not obj.visited), None)
```

If the default parameter is omitted, `next` will raise a `StopIteration` exception if no objects are found matching the criteria.

Comment: You might take advantage of the default value in case there are no such objects.  For example, `next((obj for obj in objects if not obj.visited), None)`, where if the result is None we can set `searching_done` to True.

Comment: Does that return None if no objects are found?

Comment: @JeffreyHaines: Only with DSM's addition.

Comment: Since the op question is about iterating over objects it should also be noted that `next(gen...)` is only a single item in the set.  It's probably more fitting to this question to loop over the generator: `for elem in (obj for obj in objects if not obj.visited): elem.do_something()`

Answer (score 0):

`any` returns true if any of the entries in the array are true. The `object` variable is scoped inside the `any` call, so it's not visible outside of it. You can use a generator to accomplish this:

```
not_visited = (obj for obj in objects if not obj.visited).next()
if not_visited is None:
    searching_done = True
```

This has the benefit of being concise *and* only performing exactly as many comparisons as necessary. It will also evaluate to `None` if no object satisfies the condition.

Comment: Does that return an object? called like `not_visited_obj = (obj for obj in enumerate(objects) if not obj.visited).next()`?

Comment: This won't evaluate to None if no object satisfies the condition -- it'll throw a StopIteration.  (Also won't work in modern Python.)